# Induction proof for a recurrence relation in big O notation

Tags: asymptotics

Let $T(n)$ be defined recursively by

$$T(1) = 4 $$

$$T(n) = 2T(\frac n2) +5n,\qquad n\geq 2  $$

Prove T(n) is = O(n*log(n),                                                Log is always base 2, so Log base2 (n)
T(n) <= C * n * log(n) for all n >= k      Im using k = 2 and c = 9

Base Case 2: 2 * T(1) + 5 * 2 <= 9 * 2 * log(2)     18 <= 18 = Big O
 Assume n = k
 Assume 2 * T(n/2) + 5 * n <= 9 * n * log(n)
 How do I finish the proof for n+1
Thanks for any input, all help is wanted

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: The problem is a bit flawed, since all you can say the result about is that $T(n) = O(n\log n)$ for $n=2^r$ with $r\in \Bbb Z^+ \cup 0$.

Comment: Please have a look at the source code of my edit using the edit button, and try formatting the rest.

Comment: Also, what is T(3)?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the recurrence is
$T(n) = aT(n/a) +bn$
and
$T(m) 
< c m \lg m$
for all $2 \le m < n$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
T(n)
&\lt a c(n/a)\lg(n/a)+bn\\
&=  cn(\lg(n)-\lg(a))+bn\\
&= cn\lg(n)-cn\lg(a)+bn\\
&= cn\lg(n)+n(b-c\lg(a))\\
&< cn\lg(n)
\qquad\text{if }c > b/\lg(a)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
by choosing
$c > \max(b/\lg a, \max(T(j)/(j \lg j), j=2\ to\ m))$,
$T(n) < cm\lg n$
for $n > m$
so $T(n) = O(n \lg n)$.